# findFragmentByTag returns null

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

I'm trying to implement a `DatabaseTaskManager`whichs purpose it is to manage some AsyncTasks.

On my first research I found [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) and tried to apply that to my application.

So here's what I've done:

*DatabaseActivity.java*

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_database); 

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    taskManager = (DatabaseTaskManager) fm.findFragmentByTag("DatabaseTaskManager");

    if(taskManager == null){
        taskManager = new DatabaseTaskManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(taskManager, "DatabaseTaskManager").commit();
    }else{
        reinitializeUI();
    }
}
```

*DatabaseTaskManager.java*

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallbacks = (DatabaseTaskCallbacks)activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}
```

But `findFragmentByTag` always returns null after the activity has been recreated, for example after an orientation change.

Comment: Have you called setContentView in onCreate?

Comment: Yes I did, probably should've pasted this into here. I will edit my question.

Comment: Make sure your DatabaseTaskManager extends the Fragment class from the support library (android.support.v4.app.Fragment) and not android.app.Fragment

Answer (score 2):

Rookie mistake on my side. Forgot to call `super()` in `onSaveInstanceState()`.